# How to get annotations of an Interface default method with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I thought it would behave the same as with regular methods but I can't seem to find a way. For context, I have an interface that defines some default method implementations including parameters that are extended by some TestNG classes. If those classes are annotated at the class level with the `@Test` annotation it tries to execute those methods and fails when it tries to inject values. Seems like this is by design based on the responses I got [here](https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/2983).

I was attempting the solution provided on that issue but I'm having no luck.

```
@Override
  @SneakyThrows
  public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    // See: https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/2983
    return methods.stream()
        .filter(
            it -> {
              Method method = it.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
              return !method.isAnnotationPresent(Ignore.class) && !method.isDefault();
            })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

After annotating the Interface with the `@Ignore` annotation the ethods were not skipped. During debugging it was obvious it was getting empty array of annotations for the method.

I tried adding code as follows trying to get to the declaring class (the interface) and trying there without luck.

```
        List<IMethodInstance> newMethods= new ArrayList<>();
        for(IMethodInstance it:methods){
          Method method = it.getMethod()
              .getConstructorOrMethod()
              .getMethod();
          Method parentMethod = method.getDeclaringClass().getMethod(method.getName(),
     method.getParameterTypes());
          if(!parentMethod.isAnnotationPresent(Ignore.class)){
            newMethods.add(it);
          }else{
            log.info(String.format("Skipping method %s due to @Ignore annotation!",
     it.getMethod().getMethodName()));
          }
        }
        return newMethods;
```

`AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Ignore.class)` returns null even when the JavaDocs claim it includes interfaces.

Comment: Method annotations are not inherited. There is no difference between interface methods and “regular methods” in this regard. `getDeclaringClass()` returns the class declaring the very member represented by the `Method` instance. So `method.getDeclaringClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes())` returns the same method again. You’d have to replace `method.getDeclaringClass()` by the actual interface whose `default` method you want to access. The explanation at the linked bug report is incomprehensible. What do they mean with “individual implemented methods”?

Comment: It would have been helpful to include your actual example in the question. Now that I’ve seen that you did not override the default method and there’s no need for a bridge method either, I don’t understand what TestNG does to not see the annotation. As said, the explanation is incomprehensible. [Self contained example](https://ideone.com/ahOtEz). As you can see, you can ask Reflection for either, declared methods, which excludes non overridden default methods in general, or for all public methods, which includes inherited methods, of course, including their annotations.